# Dynamic allocated lists - create a function that deletes all the elements which contain an even value

Tags: c++

As I homework, I have to create a program which deletes all the nodes which contain an even value.

Here is how I've done it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
};

void sterge(node*& p)
{
    node* t;
    t = new node;
    if (p->info % 2 == 0)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    t = p;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        if (t->next != NULL)
        {
            if (t->next->info % 2 == 0)
            {
                node* aux;
                aux = t->next;
                t->next = t->next->next;
                delete aux;
            }
        }
        t = t->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node* head = new node;
    head->info = 5;
    node* p = new node;
    node* t = new node;
    t->info = 2;
    head->next = t;
    p = head;
    node* x = new node;
    x->info = 4;
    node* w = new node;
    w->info = 6;
    t->next = x;
    x->next = w;
    w->next = nullptr;
    sterge(head);
    //Loop through the list and print each value
    while (p != NULL) {
        cout << p->info << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the output for the nodes created in main is 5 and 4.
I know the reason why but I don't know how to fix it.

Basically, I verify the next node if it has an even value, and then go to the next node. So it would look like this:

5 -> next is even so 2 is deleted
  -> go to the next node which is 4

^now the problem is that this node is not being checked because I always check the next one. So it is considered by the program valid.

So how can I fix my program?

Comment: There is a memory leak there, why do you assign `t = new node;` in the beginning? Just throwing random code to see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: Because I thought I have to initialize it? Could I use t = p directly?

Comment: Nevermind. My mistake. I didn't have to use t = new node. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can and you actually should initialize variable when you declare it and you should declare it where you need it first. So cleaner way would be `node* t = p;` and put it proper place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `continue` after your `delete`.

That way, the next iteration will begin immediately, without the rest of the current iteration being executed, so the unwanted `t = t->next` will be skipped.

Comment: Maybe. Haven't tried it. Haven't tested it. Haven't even really given it much thought to be honest.

Comment: Actually it works, but I have no idea how. I've never used continue tbh, only break lol. Might explaining what it does in this case? I will accept the answer as correct asap.

Comment: @JohnSmith Doesn't your book explain what `continue` does in a loop? Now's a great opportunity to go review its chapter on loops. I couldn't do it justice in a comment, and I'd be robbing you of a great opportunity to get some valuable research practice. :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Although I've tweaked the wording a bit if that helps

Comment: I could've looked into it online, but I thought it might work differently because of the pointers. I will check it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnSmith `continue` is `continue` and no pointer's gonna change that

Comment: Yes. I understood. I looked it up and I got how it works continue. But I don't understand how did it solve my problem and how the program is executed. I tried using the debugger but I can't figure it out. For example, in the first place when t's info is 5, what will continue do? As far as I know, it skips one iteration and it should go to the pointer with info = 4. So my problem would be the same as in the beginning. Though, using continue made it work. So I'm missing something.

Comment: @John It does not "skip one iteration". It skips the rest of _this_ iteration. The rest of this iteration is a `t = t->next` that you did not wish to perform. You could have got the same effect with some cleverly placed `else`s

Comment: So basically it takes the while from the beginning again in my case?